# What is the best way to introduce a custom UIColor to a Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I've thought of two types of implementation; which one of them is better in your opinion in terms of performance, readability and maintainability?

1. Create an extension of UIColor like this

   ```
   extension UIColor {
       class func myColor() -> UIColor {
           return UIColor(red: 128/255, green: 102/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a structure:

   ```
   struct Colors {
       static let myColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 102/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
   }
   ```

Comment: Define "better"...

Comment: I **like** the 2nd :)

Comment: The first way is clearly, objectively, better.  :D

Comment: @EricD  i'm thinking about performance, readability and maintainability. I'm new to Swift so i'm just trying to not stick with the first thing that comes in mind.

Comment: ` extension UIColor {
    
    open class var farmaOrange: UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.988, green: 0.337, blue: 0.063, alpha: 1)
    }
} `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answer:** Extension, in my professional opinion.

Think about it; you are, in philosophy, 'extending' the range of colors offered by `UIColor`. Provided that your color name is distinct and the new function follows Apple's method naming protocol (i.e. `<color name>Color`), extending `UIColor` seems neater. One or two new colors (in my opinion) don't warrant an entire dedicated `struct`.

---

**Bonus answer:** 
Where would a `struct` (or `enum`!) be a good fit?

- If your app forces replacements for the standard colors (i.e. custom
  'primary' colors)
- If your app is specifically designed to be themed / customized, it might be good have an `enum`, to serve as a concrete list for available options.
- If you can't think of standard names for the colors (`sharkBlueColor`, anyone?).
- If your app is specifically for drawing/painting (in which case a 'palette' construct might be  good idea).

... the list goes on. You must learn to discern and decide for yourself as you mature as a Swift developer!

Comment: agree, it makes discoverability much easier unless you have a reason to hide it away - e.g. a series of colour sets with an extensive list of colours - in which case probably an enum is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I use enums for this

```
enum AppColor: UInt32 {

    case DarkBlue = 0x00437C
    case LightBlue = 0x7CCEF0

    var color: UIColor {
        return UIColor(hex: rawValue)
    }

}
```

This way it is easy to reuse same color in `xib`/`storyboard` because I have hex values ready for copy/paste. And also less code needed for defining new color

For creating colors from hex value I used `UIColor` extension:

```
extension UIColor {

    public convenience init(hex: UInt32) {
        let mask = 0x000000FF

        let r = Int(hex >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(hex >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(hex) & mask

        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255

        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1)
    }

}
```

Comment: `UIColor (hex: rawValue)` ?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/